# Symfony 4 - "variable does not exist" in base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, variables

I have a blog and have two routes which redirect to my profile page and my "update profile" page

@Route("/profil/{slug}", name="profile")

@Route("/profil/{slug}/infos", name="profile_update")

And those routes have two links in my navbar **which is a part of my base.html.twig template**

So in my base.html.twig I did something like this

```
 <a href="{{ path('profile',  {'slug' : membre.slug }) }}" class="dropdown-item">Account</a>
 <a href="{{ path('profile_update',  {'slug' : membre.slug }) }}" class="dropdown-item">Update profile</a>
```

But it says "variable membre does not exist" :(

It only works in my profile route because in its template I also have those link inside the page so in the controller I did :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/profil/{slug}", name="profile")
     */
    public function profile(Membre $membre){

        return $this->render('blog/profile.html.twig', [
            'membre' => $membre
        ]);
    }
```

and it works, but base.html.twig has **NO CONTROLLER** it's just a "base" template so how am I suppose to tell it where the variable is from?

Thank you

Comment: If `Membre` is the logged-in user, you can use `app.user` in your template.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `base.html.twig` is used by all controller actions, whether the user is set as template variable or not. One solution would be to only display these links when the member variable is set:

```
{% if membre is defined %}
    <a href="{{ path('profile',  {'slug' : membre.slug }) }}" class="dropdown-item">Account</a>
    <a href="{{ path('profile_update',  {'slug' : membre.slug }) }}" class="dropdown-item">Update profile</a>
{% endif %}
```

The only other option would be to always pass that variable to the template, which will be difficult since it requires some additional input.

Comment: This condition is working but now instead of an error the links disappear since the variable is defined in only one function of my controller :/

Comment: Yes, if you always want the variable to be available you would need to provide the slug to each action, which does not seem feasible. You could also store the info in a session and then retrieve it in your template: `{% if membre is not defined%}{% set membre = app.session.membre %}{% endif %}`, but obviously that would mean that the session data needs to be up to date which might be difficult